# HttpWebRequest method HEAD returns body

Tags: c#, asp.net, httpwebrequest

My web request with the method "Head" keeps returning the body of my webpage (on localhost).
Here is how it is basically created:

```
HttpWebRequest webrequest = WebRequest.Create(url.ToString()) as HttpWebRequest;
webrequest.Method = "HEAD";
WebResponse response = webrequest.GetResponse();
```

As I put a breakpoint in my aspx.cs page, I step into the OnInit() method and also the Page_Load() method where I believe I'm not supposed to step in with a Head method request (am I wrong?).

In my Page_Load() I execute some code that I do not want to be executed when I call with the Head method, but later when I call with the Get method (once I got the headers).

Am I missing something? (not too familiar with Http requests and responses yet... :/) 
Thank you for your help!

Comment: in your request, it shows HEAD, but are you sure it shouldn't be head? lowercase instead of upper?

Comment: Does your web server support the HEAD verb properly?

Comment: Found any solution?

Answer (score 1):

Try this sample code approach ....

```
for (int i = 0; i < ParsedLinks.Count; i++)
{
        Thread.Sleep(500);
        HttpWebRequest req = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(ParsedLinks[i]);
        req.Method = "HEAD";
        req.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;
        HttpWebResponse resp = (HttpWebResponse)req.GetResponse();
        bool b_Result = int.TryParse(resp.Headers.Get("Content-Length"), out i_ContentLength);
        int i_Size = (int)(i_ContentLength / 1024);
        req.Abort();
        resp.Close();

}
```

hope it helps 
http://forums.asp.net/t/1412824.aspx/1

Answer (score 0):

The difference is, if you try to read the response you get nothing in case of HEAD.  Where as you can see the response content in case of GET

```
            var response = webrequest.GetResponse().GetResponseStream();
            Encoding encode = System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding("utf-8");
            StreamReader readStream = new StreamReader(response, encode);
            Console.WriteLine(readStream.ReadToEnd().Length) // you should see 0
            readStream.Close();
```

Comment: `webrequest.GetResponse().GetResponseHeader` ?